# query data with same id but different values oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two  tables like these

```
Person_table
| person_id | name   | surname 
--------------------------------        
     1      | name1  | surname1
--------------------------------
     2      | name2  | surname2
--------------------------------
     3      | name3  | surname3


    insurance_table

   ins_id |person_id | insurance_type |
  -------------------------------------
    001  |    1      |     5%         |
  -------------------------------------
    002  |    1     |     10%        |
  -------------------------------------
    003  |    3      |     2%         |
```

after joining as following

```
select pt.*, it.insurance_type
from person_table pt 
   join insurance_table it on it.person_id=pt.person_id
```

the query returns duplicating rows for person_id = 1.
like this

```
    |  person_id  | person_name | insurance_type |
    ----------------------------------------------
    |    1        |  name1      |    5%          |
   -----------------------------------------------
    |    1        |  name1      |    10%         |
```

the point is to return a single row for every id with additional columns according to insurance type,like this

```
|  person_id  | person_name |   type 1  |  type2   |   type3  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1        |  name1      |    5%     |  10%     |   null   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
     2        |  name2      |    null   |  null    |    2%    |
```

is it possible to implement such a query without writing pl procedure. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Same person_id twice in insurance_table? What does that mean?

Comment: @jarlh insurance_table might be a junction table that connects persons and insurances. However I agree it is confusing.

Comment: You are right. I changed the value to right one.

Comment: With the edited version,  the first question shouldn't return duplicates.  I agree with @ChrisB: you are probably looking for pivoting the insurance data,  but you probably should have two separate (insurance_type,  insurance_percentage)  fields.  In this case,  two rows with the same person_id but different insurance_type would make sense.

Comment: I've changed insurance_table and think it clears the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand, you want to  get persons with different types of insurance. If we have just 3 types its look like you need simple decode

```
select person_id, person_name, max(type1) as type1,  max(type2) as type2, max(type3) as  type3 from ( 
select pt.*, decode( it.insurance_type,'5%',it.insurance_type) as type1 
       , decode( it.insurance_type,'10%',it.insurance_type) as type2
       , decode( it.insurance_type,'2%',it.insurance_type) as type3
from person_table pt 
join insurance_table it on it.person_id=pt.person_id)
group by  person_id, person_name
```

Comment: The query is great, I tried that and was very glad. However, decode does not recognize german letters in condition quotes 'ü'. When I put non german specific symbols, it works fine.

Comment: Yes better to use an numeric code. I write sql just as idea. However, I dont understand what the problem with German symbols? Decode should correctly work with any type of data.

Comment: You are right. The solution was to add a string value to register in oracle key.

Answer (score 0):

If the person with id = 1, only exists one time in table "insurance_table" then it is not posible that the result of the query is 2 records with the person with id = 1.

If your insurance_table only has 2 columns (person_id and insurance_type) then it is not posible to make a result with the 3 types.
If this table has a third column then you could use an union statement, and for each each query another where-clause for the insurance_table.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that's how I would do that:

```
 select person_id, person_name, 
        max(case when  ins_id='001' then insurance_type end) as type1,  
        max(case when  ins_id='002' then insurance_type end) as type2, 
        max(case when  ins_id='003' then insurance_type end) as type3  
   from person_table pt 
        join insurance_table it 
          on it.person_id=pt.person_id)
  group by person_id, person_name;
```

What I don't get is if the percentages are an "attribute" of the Insurance or "the name"/"the key" of the insurance type (in the latter case, there was no need for the "ins_id" column that I've suggested to add).